# select always returns -1 while trying to read from socket and stdin

Tags: c++, select, sockets, stdin

I have the following code implemented on C++(Linux) to check on my listening socket and stdin using select. select however keeps returning -1 no matter what I try to do! What's wrong with that code :s I will appreciate any help. Thanks

```
highsock = m_sock; //listening socket

memset((char *) &connectlist, 0, sizeof(connectlist));
memset((char *) &socks, 0, sizeof(socks));

int readsocks;
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 60;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

while (1) {
    updateSelectList();
    //cout << "highest sock: " << highsock << endl;
    tempreadset = readset;
    readsocks = select(highsock+1, &tempreadset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    //cout << "# ready: " << readsocks << endl;
    if (readsocks < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        cout << "select error" << endl;
    }
    if (readsocks > 0) {
        readFromSocks();
    }
}

void readFromSocks() {
    if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readset)) {
    ...
    } else if (FD_ISSET(m_sock, &readset)) {
    ...
    }
}

void updateSelectList() {
    FD_ZERO(&readset);

    FD_SET(STDIN, &readset);
    FD_SET(m_sock, &readset);

    for (int i=0; i<MAXCONNECTIONS; i++) {
        if (connectlist[i] != 0) {
            FD_SET(connectlist[i], &readset);
            if (connectlist[i] > highsock)
                highsock = connectlist[i];
        }
    }

    highsock = max(max(m_sock, STDIN), highsock);
}
```

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but you should use `FD_COPY(&readset, &tempreadset)` to copy an `fd_set` instead of `tempreadset = readset`.

Comment: And, uhh, what error is select setting in errno?

Comment: errno is set to 9 EBADF - Bad file descriptor

What the hack?

Comment: what are the parameters for socket/setsockopt/ioctl/bind leading up to the listen?

Comment: m_sock = socket ( AF_INET,
   SOCK_STREAM,
   0 ); 
 const int on = 1;
 setsockopt ( m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof ( on ) )
 

 m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 m_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =   htonl ( INADDR_ANY );
 m_addr.sin_port = htons ( port );

 int bind_return = ::bind ( m_sock,
   ( struct sockaddr * ) &m_addr,
   sizeof ( m_addr ) );

 int listen_return = ::listen ( m_sock, MAXCONNECTIONS );

Comment: ioctl? you need to call it after setsocket to allow non-blocking ioctl( m_sock, FIONBIO, (char*)&on)

Comment: The compiler complaint about FIONBIO it could not resolve it might it be the case that I am working on Linux? I used 126 instead but nothing worked.

Comment: const int on = 1;
 if ( setsockopt ( m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof ( on ) ) == -1 )
  return false;

 int FIONBIO = 126;

 ioctl( m_sock, FIONBIO, (char*)&on);

Comment: I tried using fnctl 0_NONBLOCKIN but no way : (

Comment: void Socket::set_non_blocking ( const bool b )
{

 int opts;

 opts = fcntl ( m_sock,
   F_GETFL );

 if ( opts < 0 )
 {
  return;
 }

 if ( b ) {
  opts =  ( opts | O_NONBLOCK );
 }
 else
  opts = ( opts & ~O_NONBLOCK );
}

Answer (score 1):

Some things to change, which might help:

1) Set highsock to -1 at the top of each while loop (otherwise it may be too high, reflecting a socket that used to be art of your socket set but is now invalid)

2) Set the values in the timeval struct at the start of each loop, instead of once before the loop starts.  (Also, you might want to pass in NULL as the timeval argument just to see if that makes the problem go away... I've seen select() fail when passed a timeval that it didn't like)

Comment: I tried them both nothing happens. Here is the output:

highest sock: 3
Select failure: select returned a negative value!

Comment: I update highsock in the updateSelectList and remove any socket from connectionlist array when it is closed so setting highsock to -1 has no effect.

Comment: Except that according to the posted code, when you update highsock in updateSelectList() you are updating it to be the maximum of the other sockets and itself... so old large values of highsock will be preserved even when they are no longer appropriate.