# C select returns -1 when used with stdin

Tags: sockets, select, stdin

I am having trouble with select when fd_set contains stdin descriptor. I have found some similar questions but the answers did not help. And yes, I have read this ([select always returns -1 while trying to read from socket and stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706806/select-always-returns-1-while-trying-to-read-from-socket-and-stdin)) topic :)

Note: I am using windows, Netbeans IDE and cygwin;

Problem: Select returns -1 when fd_set contains stdin descriptor and connection descriptor. Also select works fine without stdin descriptor.

```
while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readableSocksSet);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &readableSocksSet);
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &readableSocksSet);
    i = select(serverSocket + 1, &readableSocksSet, NULL, NULL, 0);
}
```

and after this code: i == -1

Comment: Some types of files are deemed 'always readable'.  If standard input is coming from a file, it will be 'always readable'.  If it is a terminal, or some other device types, it may work.  You seem to know that you have to set the FD sets before each call — omitting that is a common mistake when first using `select()`.  Have you checked what is in `errno` when you get the -1?

Comment: Standard input is a terminal and errno is 0. Now I am even more confused.

Comment: Maybe the simulation of `select()` under Cygwin is imperfect.  POSIX says the [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) will return -1 and set `errno` if it fails.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning errno (I'm not a keen c programmer ;) ). That led me to WSAGetLastError() method which returns 10038 (Socket operation on nonsocket). I suppose I'll try to switch to MinGW and see what happens.

Comment: MinGW did not help, everything is the same, just the errno now ir 38.